# What are these things in css files?

Tags: css

I recently downloaded wordpress and I realized that on the installation page the css files it has, wordpress implements them like this:

```
 wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=6.0.2
```

What is the `ver=6.0.2` in the url? What happens if that part is removed? Or just how does it work?

Comment: Those are query strings and unless specifically looked for by the server generally does not affect the page outcome, so if you go to stackoverflow.com?abc=def you still will land at the home page. In this case though, the server is looking for a querystring "ver", and with that you can specify the version of the CSS file (Wordpress version theme I surmise...).

Comment: @code Oh ok, thank you very much, it was just what I was looking for, if you want add it as an answer to mark that my question is already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Almost) anything that follows a `?` (question mark) in a URL is part of this data called a "query string". Query strings allow you to pass data to the server via the URL without changing the target page.

Query strings are in a key-value format delimited by `&` and the key and value delimited with `=`, so a URL with a query string would look something like `https://example.com?data=something&otherdata=something+else`.

As an example: StackOverflow utilizes query strings to read what you've searched for and access it from the server, like this: [`https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=query+string`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=query+string).

Another note is that if the server doesn't recognize a query string you've provided, it is generally ignored, so if I go to [`https://stackoverflow.com?random=querystring`](https://stackoverflow.com?random=querystring) you'd still end up on the home page.

In your case, I would surmise that you are passing a version number either for the version of CSS (caching might prevent updates; passing a different querystring evades cache) or the Wordpress version you're currently using so that the server can send the relevant CSS.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (cf. [RFC 3986 Section 3.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4))

Wordpress is using the query string as a *cache buster*. Browsers might not download a file again and use their locally cached version if they think the file has not changed. Since the content of the file changes with each version, but its name does not, Wordpress is appending the query string with the version so that browsers are informed that they must download the file again (different URI, so cache is not used).